# Avoiding triggering validation when prepopulating form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a registration form which is displayed to the user with some of the fields pre-populated. That part is working fine.

However, the way I have set this up with two Register methods is triggering the form validation when the page is first displayed, instead of only when the form is submitted.

I need some direction on how to prevent this. Thanks.

### Controller

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, int? userID)
{
    if (userID != null && userID > 0)
    {
        int id = userID.Value;
        ExternalUser newUser = RepositoryHelper.GetExternalUserRepository().GetById(id);

        model.UserFirstName = newUser.NameFirst;
        model.UserLastName = newUser.NameLast;
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        try
        {
            IUnitOfWork unit = new EFUnitOfWork();
            var rep = new PersonRepository {UnitOfWork = unit};

            var entity = new Person
                {
                    NameTitle = model.NameTitle,
                    NameFirst = model.UserFirstName,
                    NameLast = model.UserLastName,
                    NameSalutation = model.NameSalutation,
                    DateOfBirth = model.DateOfBirth,
                };

            rep.Add(entity);
            unit.Commit();

            string confirmationToken = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { entity.Id, IsApproved = model.IsApproved =false }, true);
            WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

            return RedirectToAction("RegisterStepTwo", "Account");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

### View

```
@model Models.RegisterModel

<div class="content">
    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    </hgroup>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration Form</legend>
            <div id="container">
                <div class="firstContentColumn">
                    <section>
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserFirstName)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserFirstName)
                                <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserFirstName)</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserLastName)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserLastName)
                                <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserLastName)</p>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </section>
                </div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                    </section>
                </div>

            </div>
        </fieldset>  
    }
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
}
```

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: Weird, all looks fine. You've not got any extra jquery calling `.validate` on page load have you?

Comment: No, there's nothing extra calling `.validate`

Comment: Curious, if you break point the `HttpPost`, does that get hit on load?

Comment: No, that doesn't get hit on load. Thanks for your time matty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been told that using `ModelState.Clear` will prevent the initial validation, and it seems to be working perfectly.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, int? userID)
{
ModelState.Clear();

    if (userID != null && userID > 0)
    {
        int id = userID.Value;
        ExternalUser newUser = RepositoryHelper.GetExternalUserRepository().GetById(id);

        model.UserFirstName = newUser.NameFirst;
        model.UserLastName = newUser.NameLast;
    }
    return View(model);
}
```